# If $a^n=e$ for exactly one $a$ then show that $a\in Z(G)$

Tags: group-theory

The problem is,

> In a group $(G,\circ)$ if $a$ is the only element having order $n$ for some fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then prove that $a\in Z(G)$.

**Remarks:**

1. Here $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\cdots\}$
2. $Z(G)=\{x\mid x\circ g=g\circ x\ \forall g\in G\}$

***My Attempt:***

So far I can only prove that $a=a^{-1}$. This is obvious since, $\operatorname{order}(a)=\operatorname{order}(a^{-1})=n$. Since $a$ is the only element of order $n$, so we conclude that $a=a^{-1}$ or in other words $n=2$.

Can anyone help me in solving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $gx=xg$ is equivalent to $gxg^{-1}=x$.

Comment: But this hint only proves that $(gxg^{-1})^2=x^2$. From this how can we conclude that $gx=xg$?

Comment: @user170039 You want to conclude that $gxg^{-1}$ and $x$ are the same thing. The only tool you have for proving that something is $x$ is the fact that anything with the same order as $x$ must be $x$. What's the order of $gxg^{-1}$?

Comment: I get it now. Sorry, it was too trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Any conjugate of $a$ have the same order of $a$, but since there is only one element with that order we conclude any conjugate of a is equal to$ a$. Now use the hint given in the other answer